# Extending an object with multiple properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a global JavaScript object with multiple properties and functions that I am creating it this way:

```
myObject = {};
```

I thought that I can easily extend this object by creating something like this

```
myObject = { propA1 : null, ....., propAN : null};
```

instead of

```
myObject.propA1 = null;
myObject......;
myObject.propAN = null;
```

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: When you say "extend". do you mean to add more properties to the object? Or do you the OOP "extend" meaning "inherit"ed by other objects?

Comment: I meant the object itself and not the class

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you write `myObject = { ... }`, you're creating a brand-new object and setting `myObject` to point to it.
The previous value of `myObject` is thrown away.

Instead, you can use jQuery:

```
jQuery.extend(myObject, { newProperty: whatever });
```

Comment: I guess I should go with this solution but I am wondering how expensive it is. My object is very heavy

Comment: @user: This doesn't create any copies; it simply assigns references.  It should be fast.

Comment: OP asked about Javascript, not jquery. It also takes away from truely learning Javascript objects.

Answer (score 14):

Without jQuery, you could create an array of objects with something like this:

```
[{'key': 'atuhoetu', 'value': 'uehtnehatn'},{...}]
```

If you don't care about compatibility, recent browsers should support this:

```
var newObj = {prop1: 'val', prop2: 'val'};
Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function (item) {
    myObject[item] = newObj[item];
});
```

This will iterate over all items in newObject and add them to myObj.

Comment: Very elegant solution but I guess jQuery Extend is doing the same

Comment: Yeah, I guess it just depends on if you're using jQuery.  I use server-side javascript, and this allows code to be used on the server AND the client...

Comment: Thank you.
I am already using jQuery anyway.
Actually, I was looking for the concept of partial class that we have .NET so I can spread the same object in multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

Or, something cleaner:

```
function extend(target, source){
    for(prop in source){
        target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
}
```

If you use it the following way:

```
var objA = {a: "a"};
var objB = {b: "b", c: "c"};
extend(objA, objB);
```

The result will be:

```
objA = {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"};
```